# How to create a Membership in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I have create a asp membership in asp.net it is working fine .But,when i try to to register a new member password will not accept without a special Character ,how can solve this problem please help me........

```
 <providers>
      <clear/>
           <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
           <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0, 
     Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="Mybusinessconnection" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"  
   applicationName="MyBusinessApp" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
   maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" minRequiredPasswordLength="4"/>
 </providers>
 </membership>
```

This is what i'm using for membership...

Comment: You need to share code and/or provide a more detailed description. Are you getting an error? Which error? What part of your code is failing?

Comment: Hi i have share my code please check it and where i can change the code please help me..

Answer (score 6):

You can handle this with the Membership's [MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters.aspx) property.

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
  userIsOnlineTimeWindow = "20>
  <providers>
    <add
      name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="SqlServices"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
      />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

- Important note: Microsoft itself spelled it wrong, it's case sensitive and must be spelled `minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters`(changed it above). Someone [mentioned this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters.aspx#1) as comment below.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for Giving responce i have try above code but it showing error like " Attribute not recognized 'minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters' (D:\victor\MyBusinessApp\web.config line 32)

Answer (score 1):

This thread should help you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1285512.aspx/1

You need to create a custom Membership Provider in your web.config and set the `minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters` property to `="0"`.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving responce i have try to put minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters property to ="0".But it showing error like Attribute not recognized 'minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters' (D:\victor\MyBusinessApp\web.config line 32)

Comment: The A in alpha should be lowercase :)